# How to set On click event in KnockoutJs

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mvc

I am new to knockoutjs
In my project I have list of Reports.
when a user clicks on one of the Reports,
The next div(ReportContentdiv) should show all the 
Sub Reports(SubReportName, SubReportDate, SubReportNote, SubReportType) of the report in tabular format.
I dont know how to do it.
Any help is greatly appreciated

Here is my code

@@@@@@

```
--HTML
<div id="ReportNamediv">
<ul class="ulclass">
    <div data-bind="template: {name: 'ReportData',foreach:$root.Report}">
    </div>
</ul>
</div>
<div id="ReportContentdiv">
    //Show Report Content here
</div>
```

@@@@@@@@

```
--Script
 <script type="text/html" id="ReportData">
    <li><a href="#"><span data-bind="text: ReportName"></span></a></li>
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

t's a little difficult to give a precise answer without seeing your javascript model, so I will make some assumptions. Note: I have changed the name $root.Report to $root.Reports, as it is a list the plural makes more sense.

**Javascript Model**

```
var model = {
    Reports: ko.observableArray([]), //An observable list of reports...you can set this yourself.
    SelectedReport: ko.observable(null) 
};
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="ReportNamediv">
    <ul class="ulclass" data-bind="foreach:Reports">
          <li>
             <a data-bind="click:$root.SelectedReport">
                      <span data-bind="text: ReportName"></span>
             </a>
         </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="ReportContentdiv" data-bind="with:SelectedReport">
    <table data-bind="foreach:SubReports">
        <tr>
            <td data-bind="text:SubReportName"></td>
            <td data-bind="text:SubReportDate"></td>
            <td data-bind="text:SubReportNote"></td>
            <td data-bind="text:SubReportType"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: It is close to what I am looking for. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The basic approach to doing this is to have a `SelectedReport` observable that stores the report the user selected. Then we can leverage a `with:` binding to change the context of the binding specifically to `SelectedReport` which will also handle the scenario of no report being selected elegantly for you.

Your model would look something like the following:

```
var model = {
   Reports: ko.observableArray(),
   SelectedReport: ko.observable(),
   ViewReport: function(model) {
       this.SelectedReport(model);
   }
};

function Report() {
    var self = this;
    self.Name = ko.observable();
    self.Date = ko.observable();
    self.Note = ko.observable();
    self.Type = ko.observable();
}
```

Then your html markup would look something like this:

```
<div id="ReportNamediv">
<ul class="ulclass" data-bind="foreach: Reports">
    <li>
         <span data-bind="text: Name()"></span>
         <button data-bind="click: ViewReport">View Report</button
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
<div id="ReportContentdiv" data-bind="with: SelectedReport()">
     <ul>
         <li>
              <label>Name:</label>
              <span data-bind="text: Name()"></span>
         </li>
         <li>
              <label>Date:</label>
              <span data-bind="text: Date()"></span>
         </li>
         <li>
              <label>Note:</label>
              <span data-bind="text: Note()"></span>
         </li>
         <li>
              <label>Type:</label>
              <span data-bind="text: Type()"></span>
         </li>
     </ul>
</div>
```